# How the Drools xls condition check works?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, rule-engine

I am working on Drools rule engine using the XLS file. I have some set of rules, in that I wanted to know the flow of checking the rules. For example, consider I have a set of rules in multiple rows, So how will the condition check will work? From top to bottom or bottom to top?

Also if there is any reference link, that will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every row in the excel file will be translated in a Drools rule.

You don't get to choose the order in which the rules are executed against the facts, and it could also lead to multiple results. This is the same behaviour as you were writing the rules by hand.

While using guided decision tables in Business Central you have also the concept of [hit policy](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.48.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#hit-policies-con) that lets you control the evaluation, but such concept is not present in XLS files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll check and let you know if that helps.